# Return count of ASCII characters in order of user input C

Tags: arrays, c, character, ansi-c

I need to return a count of ASCII characters in order of their appearance in a character array received by user input

My current solution is returning characters in ascending order of their appearance on the ASCII table rather than in order of their input by the user

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char string[16];
  int c = 0, count[128] = {0}, x, counted = 0;

  printf("Enter a word>\n");
  scanf("%s", string);

  while (string[c] != '\0') {
    if(string[c] >= '!' && string[c] <= '~'){
      x = string[c] - '!';
      count[x]++;
    }
    c++;
  }

  for (c = 0; c < 128; c++){
    if(count[c] > 1){
    printf("Duplicate letter: %c, Occurrences: %d\n", c + '!', count[c]);
      counted++;
    }
  }

  if(counted < 1){
    printf("No duplicates found\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Example input:**

AAAAaaaaBBBbb99

**Desired output:**

Duplicate letter: A, Occurrences: 4
 
Duplicate letter: a, Occurrences: 4
 
Duplicate letter: B, Occurrences: 3
 
Duplicate letter: b, Occurrences: 2
 
Duplicate letter: 9, Occurrences: 2

**My current (wrong) output:**

Duplicate letter: 9, Occurrences: 2
 
Duplicate letter: A, Occurrences: 4
 
Duplicate letter: B, Occurrences: 3
 
Duplicate letter: a, Occurrences: 4
 
Duplicate letter: b, Occurrences: 2

Any help here is greatly appreciated

Comment: First off, you are writing past the end of your array.  You declared `char string[15]`, which means it can hold at most 14 characters plus the terminating null byte.  Yet your sample input contains 15 characters, meaning you will write 16 characters to `string`.  Fix your array size problems before doing anything else.

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to help but declarations of array sizes in C don't require you to account for the null at the end - you might be getting mixed up with another language?

https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-arrays

Comment: Wrong, wrong, wrong.  You *do* need to include the null byte.  Trust me on this.  This is the *first* thing you should learn when using strings in C.  One more time:  Fix your memory bug, or remove your question.  You are just wasting people's time at this point.

Comment: @DavideLorino: For what it's worth, you might want to reference a web site that actually discusses `char` arrays in C.

Comment: Sure, apologies for my misunderstanding, I have fixed it. Now that we're in a happy place and the null is accounted for I hope we can address the actual question?

Comment: Your output is coming out in the order of the character values, rather than where they're first seen, is because you are iterating over the `count` array.  If you want the order in which they first occur, you need to iterate over the original string again, flagging the entries after you output them so you don't output them more than once.

Comment: @user3386109 A sort operation is unnecessary.  A second pass over the input string is all that's needed.  Once the count for a letter has been output, its entry in the `count` array can be set to -1 to indicate is has already been shown.

Comment: @TomKarzes ok, thanks Tom. Forgive my ignorance here (I started using C two weeks ago) but how might I implement this solution?

Comment: @TomKarzes Ah, I was only looking at the example output, and concluded that the items were arranged in order of descending count. But after rereading the question, I believe you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a very elegant solution but it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char string[1024];
    int c = 0;
    int count[128] = {0};
    int x;
    int counted = 0;

    printf("Enter a word:\n");
    scanf("%1023s", string);

    while (string[c] != '\0') {
        if(string[c] >= '!' && string[c] <= '~'){
            x = string[c] - '!';
            count[x]++;
        }
        c++;
    }

    int j = 0;
    while (string[j] != '\0') {
        int ch = string[j] - '!';

        if(count[ch] > 1){
            printf("Duplicate letter: %c, Occurrences: %d\n", ch + '!', count[ch]);
            count[ch] = -1;
            counted++;
        }

        j++;
    }

    if(counted < 1){
        printf("No duplicates found.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is great, much appreciated!